# Android Tab bar

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

How can i navigate in an application with a tabhost with few tabs with all kind of different ui elements in them and the tabs are always there. In every activity that I start and etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This to start the new Activity

```
 View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("tab1", new Intent(this,tab1.class)  
                                                             .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
                                                             .getDecorView();                  

setContentView(view);
```

Comment: the class you want to open write its name

Comment: can i use it as onClickListener for a button?